# Does PCA always have to reduce dimensionality?

Tags: linear-transformations, finance, matrix-decomposition

I came across [this paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~bvr/pubs/RPCA.pdf) where the authors implement a regularized learning model to estimate the covariance matrix of a dataset. The authors say they "...propose a regularized form of Principal Component Analysis (PCA)..."

However, from what I can gather from the paper, ultimately the model **predicts the full covariance matrix** of S&P500 (time series) price data i.e. the model is trained on data up until day T and then attempts to predict the covariance matrix of the data until T+10. No dimensionality reduction has taken place.

Granted, the paper does show how a factor model was learned to be able to predict future covariances between stock prices. What I don't understand though is how this is related to PCA - I always thought PCA involved reducing the dimensionality of a dataset / matrix.

Perhaps I am getting confused with terminology. Does PCA always involve reducing the dimensionality of a dataset?

Answer (score 1):

The PCA is a method utilized for reducing dimensionality however if the matrix is full rank then you wouldn't have any dimensionality reduction. In the paper you mention if you read on page 3 you have the following

> We consider the problem of learning a factor model without knowledge
>   of the number of factors. Specifically, we want to estimate a $M × M$
>   covariance matrix $Σ∗$ from samples $x(1), . . . , x(N) ∼ N (0, Σ∗)$,
>   where $Σ∗$ is the sum of a symmetric matrix $F∗ ≽ 0$ and a diagonal matrix
>   $R∗ ≽ 0.$ These samples can be thought of as generated by a factor model
>   of the form $x(n) = F 1 2 ∗ z(n) + w(n)$ , where $z(n) ∼ N (0, I)$
>   represents a set of common factors and $w(n) ∼ N (0, R∗)$ represents
>   residual noise. **The number of factors is represented by $rank(F∗)$, and
>   it is usually assumed to be much smaller than the dimension $M$**.
>
> Granted, the paper does show how a factor model was learned to be able
>   to predict future covariances between stock prices. What I don't
>   understand though is how this is related to PCA - I always thought PCA
>   involved reducing the dimensionality of a dataset / matrix.

If you know what the PCA is you'd realize it is generated from computing the covariance matrix then typically choosing $K$ factors from this covariance matrix which are responsible for $90$% of the variance. There are Krylov based methods which wouldn't construct a full matrix.